# Keep div open on hover effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am looking at using the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/webdevem/4RgTS/

But I need a way of making sure the div that appears to stay open if you hover over the div that appears.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#toggleSwitch_j").hover(

    function() {
        $("#theBox_3").slideDown(500);
    }, function() {
        $("#theBox_3").slideUp(500);
    });


    $("#StayOpen").hover(
        function() {
            $("#theBox_2").slideDown(500);
        }, function() {
            $("#theBox_2").slideUp(500);
        });
    });


<a href="#" id="toggleSwitch_j">jQuery Hover</a><div id="theBox_3">Peek-a-boo!</div>

#theBox_3, #theBox_2{
    display: none; 
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ddf;
    position: absolute;
}
#toggleSwitch_j, #StayOpen {
 background-color: #cacaca;            
}
```

Comment: do u want the div remain hove even if you remove the mouse from the element?

Comment: the second example in your link does what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [demo on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4RgTS/406/) with a text input to try writing and CSS modification for CSS animation(transition).

## jQuery

```
// Function fires when hover on the link
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(document).on('hover', '.hover-me', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest("div").find(".pop-on-hover").removeClass("closed").addClass("opened");

    });

    // Function fires when click anywhere outside the slided div
    $(document).click(function (event) {
        var clickover = $(event.target);
        var _opened = $(".pop-on-hover").hasClass("pop-on-hover opened");
        if (_opened == true && !clickover.hasClass("hover-me") && !clickover.hasClass("pop-on-hover") && clickover.parents('.pop-on-hover').length == 0) {
            event.preventDefault();
            CloseHovered();
        }
    });
    // Close hovered panel function
    function CloseHovered() {
        $(".pop-on-hover").removeClass("opened").addClass("closed");
    }
});
```

## CSS

```
  body {
     background-color: #eef;     
  }
  .pop-on-hover {
      border: 1px solid #000;
      width: 200px;
      background-color: #ddf;
      height:0px; 
      overflow:hidden;
      -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
      -moz-transition: all .25s ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all .25s ease-out;
      transition: all .25s ease-out;
  }
  #toggleSwitch_j, #StayOpen {
   background-color: #cacaca;

  }
  .pop-on-hover.closed {
     height:0px; 

  }
  .pop-on-hover.opened {
     height:80px; 
      -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
      -moz-transition: all .25s ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all .25s ease-out;
      transition: all .25s ease-out;
  }
```

## Update

**You may don't use this part or use it in another way if you need it opened.**

```
   if (_opened == true && !clickover.hasClass("hover-me") && !clickover.hasClass("pop-on-hover") && clickover.parents('.pop-on-hover').length == 0) {
     event.preventDefault();
     CloseHovered();
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

For this, you need to comment the `slideUp`.

**For instance,**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#toggleSwitch_j").hover(

    function() {
        $("#theBox_3").slideDown(500);
    }, function() {
        //$("#theBox_3").slideUp(500);
    });


    $("#StayOpen").hover(
    function() {
        $("#theBox_2").slideDown(500);
    }, function() {
        //$("#theBox_2").slideUp(500);
    });
});
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4RgTS/401/)**

By doing this, it is made sure that the div that appears to stay open if you hover over the div that appears like you have mentioned.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is also a great solution but again if I put any content inside of the div id="theBox_3" it just makes the div disappear again.

Answer (score 1):

Try something similar

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#toggleSwitch_j").mouseover(

    function() {
        $("#theBox_3").slideDown(500);
    });
   $("#theBox_3").mouseleave(function(e) {
         console.log($(e.target));
        $("#theBox_3").slideUp(500);
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gt06ajna/2/

Comment: This is also a great solution but again if I put any content inside of the div id="theBox_3" it just makes the div disappear again.

Answer (score 0):

try with this below code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var divBox = $("#theBox_3");
  $("#toggleSwitch_j").hover( function() {
    divBox.slideDown(500);
  });
  divBox.mouseout(function() {
    $(this).slideUp(500);
  });

});
```

Comment: This is also a great solution but again if I put any content inside of the div id="theBox_3" it just makes the div disappear again.

Comment: any content ?? can you update jsfeddle with what ever content you have.

Answer (score 0):

I would say no need to comment it should be removed if there is no use and your function should be this

```
$("#toggleSwitch_j").hover(

function() {
    $("#theBox_3").slideDown(500);
});


$("#StayOpen").hover(
    function() {
        $("#theBox_2").slideDown(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey, this solutions great, however if I hover over any content inside of the div it disappears, how do I prevent that?